# Paramiko exec_command does not execute the command

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

What is the way to run a .bat (or Python) script on a remote Windows server 2016? SSH server is installed and works correctly.

I tried using Paramiko, but it didn't bring any result:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ip', username='root', password='pass')
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stder = ssh.exec_command('C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/main/videos/uniq.bat')
```

What am I doing wrong? The script does not run. However, if you run it manually, it works well.

The batch file is:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp4') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -vf noise=alls=1:allf=t "%%~nG_1.mp4"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `SSHClient.exec_command` only starts an execution of the command. If you do not wait for it to complete and immediately kill the session, the command is killed along with it.

The most trivial way to wait for command to complete is reading its output to the end:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
stdout.channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
output = stdout.readlines()
```

If this won't fix the problem on its own, it will at least collect any error output to help you identifying the (other) problem.